# Can I see players stats during the half-time?

Tags: fifa-14

Did this feature vanish or something? I can't seem to find where to preview my players stats during the half-time in fifa14?

I can see it at the end of the match but what about the half-time or when the game is paused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found it. While paused, navigate onto the middle box in the right and use the right stick to swap to between players ratings, performance, etc